# C:\DataEverywhere>databaseconnector.exe -q WorkOrderDetails

Tags: google-sheets-api, ini

I am trying to get data to export to Google Sheets using an api called DataEverywhere. I believe I've followed the instructions exactly, but they are kind of vague and there is no one I can call for support. Does anybody have any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong? Below is the error that I am getting when executing the `DataEverywhere.exe` file as well as the `.ini` file contents that it is referring to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
C:\DataEverywhere>databaseconnector.exe -q WorkOrderDetails
Configuration parsed from connections.ini. 1 queries found.
Running query WorkOrderDetails
Error running query WorkOrderDetails.
ServiceStack.WebServiceException: Not Found
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ThrowWebServiceException[TResponse](Exception ex, String requestUri)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ThrowResponseTypeException[TResponse](Object request, Exception ex, String requestUri)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.HandleResponseException[TResponse](Exception ex, Object request, String requestUri, Func`1 createWebRequest, Func`2 getResponse, TResponse& response)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
   at DataEverywhere.DatabaseConnector.Utilities.QueryRunner.RunUpload(QueryConfiguration query)
Finished.
```

Here is my `connections.ini` file:

```
;
; YOU MUST DELETE THESE SAMPLE QUERIES IN ORDER FOR THE CONNECTOR TO RUN
;        but feel free to edit these samples as a starting point for your own 
;        don't forget to edit the login information at the bottom 


[Query WorkOrderDetails]
Database=OleDb
ConnectionString=Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
Source=C:\DataEverywhere\WorkOrderDetails.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;

Query=SELECT * from Test_Table


FeedId=8f5dcbc6-da73-4ccb-92aa-a184deca253d


[Data Everywhere]
Server=https://www.dataeverywhere.com
Email=debra@timacinc.com
Password=Password!
```